# How to MySQL DISTINCT(COUNT) Returning Same number of rows for different criteria?

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by, distinct

I have two queries I inherited to pull total patient counts for different role codes, the problem is, they are returning the same number - I know now that the DISTINCT is producing this because of the one-to-many relationships in the tables described below, but am unsure how to add additional criteria to the query to isolate:

Query 1 (Results should theoretically be smaller

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT p.patient)
FROM react r
INNER JOIN CasesR cr
ON cr.globalid = r.globalid
LEFT JOIN profile p
ON cr.globalid = p.globalid
WHERE r.desc = 'A'
AND cr.rcode = 'PS'
```

Query 1 (Results should theoretically be much larger)

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT p.patient)
FROM react r
INNER JOIN CasesR cr
ON cr.globalid = r.globalid
LEFT JOIN profile p
ON cr.globalid = p.globalid
WHERE r.desc = 'A'
```

**react Key Fields**

```
 rrecordid (PK)
 globalid (Multiples in table IE: rrecordid=1,globalid=122; rrecordid=2,globalid=333)
 desc (Multiples in table IE: rrecordid=1,globalid=122; rrecordid=2,globalid=333)
```

**CasesR Key Fields**

```
 crecordid (PK)
 globalid 
 (Multiples in table IE: crecordid=1,globalid=122;crecordid=2,globalid=333)
 rcode (enum: 'A','B','C','D') 
 (multiples, globalid=122;rcode=A; globalid=122;rcode=B)
```

**Profile Key Fields**

```
 globalid (PK)
 patient (Multiples in table IE: globalid=1,patient=122;globalid=2,patient=122)
```

So how can alter this query to get the true counts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample data that illustrates the two different queries and how they differ, and include your expected results?

Comment: Your theory of smaller set with AND cr.rcode = 'PS' is not guaranteed... if all patients have 'PS' as the rcode.

Comment: BTW, the `LEFT JOIN` can be replaced by `INNER JOIN` since you count not NULL distinct `p.patient`

Comment: check `SELECT DISTINCT r.globalid` instead of `SELECT count(DISTINCT p.patient)`, I think they are the same for both queries, hence the JOIN on `patients` produces the same set of patients.

Comment: @DRapp, you are quite right, many do have the PS code, so therein lies an issue - some patients also have other codes, So if patient 232 has rcode 'A' and another record with RCODE 'PS' I obviously get the double count - not sure where to go.

Comment: But actually you are NOT getting double counted via the distinct.  If one patient has multiple entries, it will only get counted ONCE even though you are looking for the "PS" instance of it.  That said, what is it you are actually looking for. rcode "PS" doesn't even match your enum listing.

Answer (score 0):

To bring together what the comments above are getting at . . . your query *is* giving you the true counts. Your first query (with the `AND cr.rcode = 'PS'`) means this:

> Find all `profile` records that (1) have a corresponding record in `react` with `desc = 'A'` *and* (2) have a corresponding record in `casesr` with `rcode = 'PS'`. How many distinct values are there for those `profile` records' `patient` fields?

Your second query (without the `AND cr.rcode = 'PS'`) means the same thing, except that restriction #2 is changed from "have a corresponding record in `casesr` with `rcode = 'PS'`" to just "have a corresponding record in `casesr`". Naturally, since that's a looser restriction, it will never yield a *lesser* value; but it can certainly yield the *same* value.

You say that you inherited these queries; are you sure that the person who wrote them didn't actually *intend* for them to usually give the same result? Maybe it's fairly unusual that a  `patient` will meet all of the requirements of the second query without meeting the slight additional requirement of the first.